# JSON data in Preview tab appearing in different order from Response tab(Network Panel)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The official [doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading#preview_a_resource) offers no concrete explanation for the difference(s). 
I am sending JSON response from my server and the `Preview` tab is showing the data in different order from `Response` tab.

The `Response` tab is showing the correct order, & the `Preview` tab is not.

The actual data as it's rendered on the screen is in the same order as the `Preview` tab (incorrect order).

My question is: Why is there discrepancy between the Preview and the Response tab in the order the data is displayed ?

Comment: Maybe the Preview tab is sorting the data in some way? Can you post screenshots?

Comment: Objects don't keep the insertion order of keys.

Comment: Objects? As in Javascript? The preview tab might be implemented in JS but that smells a bit. A JSON document is not equivalent to a JS Object. Is it?